# How to concatenate and match string in from one pandas dataframe column to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on two pandas dataframes and want to match a string (strings were derived by concatenating three columns) from `df1`. How do match the generated string to a column in `df2` and if there is then I would like to extract the remaining string in the matched cell.

df1

```
id c_id code1  code2  status
1    9    ceo    ceo    ?
2    9    ned    ned
3    9    ned    chair
4    2    ed     ned
5    2    ned    ed
6    9    chair  ceo
7    2    chair  chair
```

df2

```
c_id   gender  role        ex                code
2      male     chair   ,ceo,ned,          2.male.chair.,ceo,ned,
2      male     cahir   ,chair,ned,        2.male.ned.,chair,ned,  
2      female   ed      ,ned,              2.female.ed.,ned,
6      female   ed      ,ceo,chair,        6.female.ed.,ceo,chair,
6      male     chair   ,ed,ceo,           6.male.chair.,ed,ceo,
9      female   ed      ,ceo,chair,        9.female.ed.,ceo,chair,
9      female   chair   ,ceo,ned,          9.female.chair.,ceo,ned,
9      male     ceo     ,chair,(in ft10),  9.male.ceo.,chair,(in ft10),
```

The goal is fill column `df1['status']` by concatenating `['c_id', 'code1', 'code2']` matching it with `df2['code']`

Concatenation: `df1['string'] = df1.apply(lambda x: f'{v["c_id"]}.female.{v["code1"]}.,{v["code2"]},', axis=1)`

`print df1['string']`

```
0  9.female.ceo.,ceo,
1  9.female.ned.,ned,
2  9.female.ned.,chair,
3  2.female.ed.,ned,
4  2.female.ned.,ed,
5  9.female.chair.,ceo,
6  2.female.chair.,chair,
```

current solution: `df1['c_id'].map(df2[df2['gender'].str.contains('female')]['ex'])`

The `df2['ex']` value is basically what i need, if there is a match on `df['code']`

**Expected results:** df1

```
id c_id code1  code2      status
1    9    ceo    ceo    
2    9    ned    ned
3    9    ned    chair
4    2    ed     ned     ,ned,
5    2    ned    ed
6    9    chair  ceo     ,ceo,ned,
7    2    chair  chair
```

I've hit a serious block with this one so any suggestion or help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge using desired columns based on your condition

```
df1.merge(df2[['c_id','role', 'ex']], left_on = ['c_id', 'code1'], right_on = ['c_id','role'], how = 'left').fillna('')

    id  c_id    code1   code2   role    ex
0   1   9       ceo     ceo     ceo     ,chair,(in ft10),
1   2   9       ned     ned     
2   3   9       ned     chair       
3   4   2       ed      ned     ed      ,ned,
4   5   2       ned     ed      
5   6   9       chair   ceo     chair   ,ceo,ned,
6   7   2       chair   chair   chair   ,ceo,ned,
```

Comment: What does the # do?

Comment: @Datanovice, sorry that was just some extra code I had commented out. Forgot to delete it

Comment: @Vaishali - it is possible `df1['status']` without merging both dataframes?

Comment: Oh you mean you want to add status column to df1 without using merge? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: duh, should have guessed that! thanks as always! @Vaishali